# Should this question closed as duplicate without a link to the duplicate be reopened?

Tags: support, status-completed, duplicate-answers

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12602289/210336) is closed as duplicate, but there is no link to the question it is supposed to be a duplicate of. I don't know exactly how closing as duplicate works, but I always thought that a link was part of that process.

The OP is wondering about the same thing and is understandably not happy.

Imho, the question should be reopened until the link is provided. I ran into this question with the same/similar problem and would like to see the other question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a question is closed as a duplicate, the Community User edits the post and inserts a link:

```
> **Possible Duplicate:**  
> [Title of duplicate question](http://link.to/duplicate/question)  

<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->
```

The OP however must have been editing the post at the time the link was inserted; his edit conflicted and the link was removed again (edits at 14:18 and 14:19 respectively). See the [post revision history, revs 4 and 5](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12602289/revisions).

I've re-instated the link with a manual edit.